# .bib file causing bibtex to crash using vancouver style, no errors in log

Tags: bibtex, errors

I am currently writing a thesis using the vancouver style, and I have encountered an error.

When I add any more citations to my .bib file (using jabref or otherwise), when I next go to compile, bibtex crashes and will no longer resolve until I load up a previous version of the .bib file.

Previously, there were lots of errors in the log file, but having cleaned them up, there now appears to be no log file when it crashes, and the problem has not resolved.

[The chapters and .bib file can be found here.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xh1utm60vldzkl9/RFxwchWx0h)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} 
\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} 
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pbox}
%\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true} 
\title{\ttitle}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\mainmatter 

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\input{./Chapters/01_introduction}
\input{./Chapters/02_litreview} 
\input{./Chapters/03_general_materials_and_methods}
\input{./Chapters/04_up_experimental} 
\input{./Chapters/05_mycoplasma_experimental} 
\input{./Chapters/06_general_discussion_and_conclusions} 

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}

\appendix 

%\input{./Appendices/AppendixB}
%\input{./Appendices/AppendixC}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\backmatter

\label{Bibliography}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\bibliographystyle{vancouver} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}
```

Comment: @rorance_: I take it you are the one who asked the question? In that case you seem to have two accounts. You can have them merged by following the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Where is the end of the `titlepage` and `center` envs? Plus, how are we suppose to to compile this when it include stuff that we clearly do not have access to (the chapters).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  It's important that it's *minimal* too --- include only enough to reproduce the error and nothing more.  Look into the `mwe` package for dummy text facilities.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly not a `bibtex` issue as this compiles just fine

I've added `url` and outcommented `\hypersetup` as no hyperref was added in the example.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} 
\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} 
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pbox}
%\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}


% where does this come from?
%\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true} 

\usepackage{url}


\title{\ttitle}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}
```

---

WHOAA, a little too fast. There are bibtex errors as well.

- a load of empty authors warnings
- too many commas in name
- repeated entry

Try compiling my code above, latex, bibtex, then look in the bibtex logfile (.blg), there you will find the errors ioncluding references to line numbers in `Bibliography.bib`

Comment: The error still happens if I make those two amendments daleif. The error log brings up this message Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations. ! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.449 \end{document} ?

Comment: the please post some code that produces that error. We do not own crystal balls, so we cannot tell fortunes or see what you are doing. BTW: Are you even citing anything?